# Why is Azure Repos Git Checkout sometimes returning a Status code 128?

Tags: git, azure-devops

We've migrated from a on premise GitBlit to Azure DevOps last week.

Our builds are now suffering from periodic error while cloning the git repo. See example output. Main error is probaby **returned status code 128**

We are doing quiet a number of builds a day, and each build has multiple checkouts of different git repositories.

Anybody has a clue?

> ---
>
> 04:51:50  ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' 04:51:50
> hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command
> "C:\jenkins_opt\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress
> --depth=1 -- https://company@dev.azure.com/company/GLIMS/_git/glims_glims-bin
> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128: 04:51:50  stdout:  04:51:50  stderr: warning: -----------------
> SECURITY WARNING ---------------- 04:51:50  warning: | TLS certificate
> verification has been disabled! |
>
> ---
>
> error: RPC failed; curl 56 Recv failure: Connection was reset 04:51:50
> fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
> 04:51:50  fatal: early EOF 04:51:50  fatal: fetch-pack: invalid
> index-pack output
>
> ---

Comment: are you going through a proxy?

Comment: There's a lot of IT security software... so that could act as a proxy...